# "$bluetooth_device_name is requesting access to this computer" - what does this mean?

Tags: kde, bluetooth

I've bought Sony WI-1000X bluetooth headset.

When I connected it to my Debian Stretch computer (via bluetooth) for the first time, I got a popup ([screenshot](https://dump.bitcheese.net/files/zuzusyk/Screenshot_20190825_022951.png)), which said

```
LE_WI-1000X is requesting access to this computer
```

The available buttons are:

1. Trust and authorize
2. Authorize
3. Deny

What do the buttons do?

Answer (score 3):

The device is trying to pair with your computer via Bluetooth.
Pairing is the security feature to allow communication between the two devices. Trust and authorize would allow the device to pair with your computer and would in the future automatically authorize pairing

Authorize would pair the devices but you may have to select this option in the future again

Deny would refuse pairing between your device and computer

*Edit*
This page has some useful information about Bluetooth security:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/bluetooth-security